# Creating a Regular expression which matches python tuple structure

Tags: javascript, python, regex, web-applications

I'm doing a JavaScript plugin, launched at every page-load, that replaces every matching structure with a link... That link redirects to a web application/database. A resource for coders of the Mount&Blade game.

In theory is easy, but I've found an huge obstacle in my way to the success: Regular expressions.

Even helped by a program named QuickRegex I can't get the structure to match. Or if I don't do a proper conditioning it outputs wrong results. The matching structure is as follows:

```
(item_set_slot, "itm_heavy_crossbow", slot_item_multiplayer_item_class),
```

I want to pick `item_set_slot` and turn it into a link to `http://mbcommands.ollclan.eu/#$1`

---

This is the code I'm using, that works, more or less. ;)

```
/* Mount&Blade Command Database Linking by Swyter */
function swymbcommandshooker(){
/* Regular HTML Expressions */
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML.replace(/[\(]([a-zA-Z_]+)[\,]/gi, "(<a href='http://mbcommands.ollclan.eu/#$1' title='[?] Take an look in the Command Database' target='_blank'>$1</a>,");

/* Python highlighter Support...*/
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML.replace(/&#40;</span>([_a-z]+)\,/gi, "&#40;</span><a href='http://mbcommands.ollclan.eu/#$1' title='[?] Take an look in the Command Database' target='_blank'>$1</a>,");

}
addOnloadHook( swymbcommandshooker );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it works, 'more or less', what's the problem then?

Comment: I want to find a regular expression that fully covers the structure.The current code is more a hack than a real solution...

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use the JSON serializer/deserializer in the Python standard library and save yourself some hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I'm not sure if I have understand you correctly, but if you really just want the match "item_set_slot" in "(item_set_slot, "itm_heavy_crossbow", slot_item_multiplayer_item_class)," the following regex should do:

```
/^\(([a-z_]+),/i
```

The JavaScript to generate the URL could look like this:

```
var tuple = '(item_set_slot, "itm_heavy_crossbow", slot_item_multiplayer_item_class),';
var url = tuple.replace(/^\(([a-z_]+),.*/i, 'http://mbcommands.ollclan.eu/#$1');
```

Note the appended `.*` in the regex, which is needed to match the rest of the tuple.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, a year ago, but hey. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hehe, yeah. Realized the date right after I had wrote the answer. Whatever, maybe it's of some use anyway ;)